# Finding a closed form of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\ln n}}{n!} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, closed-form

How would I find a closed form of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^{\ln n}}{n!} $?

By the ratio test, the series converges for all x:

$$ \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \left| \frac{x^{\ln (n+1)}n!}{x^{\ln n}(n+1)!} \right| = \underset{n \to \infty}{\lim} \left| \frac{x^{\ln(1+n^{-1})}}{n+1} \right| = 0$$

I've tried differentiating and integrating the series, but to no luck.

Comment: Hint: use a change of base to get an $e^{\ln n}$ expression in the numerator.

Comment: Notice that $x^{\log n} = n^{\log x}$. Substituting $u = \log x$ and assuming $u > 0$, the corresponding series $$ f(u) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^u}{n!} $$ interpolates $e$ times the Bell numbers, thanks to the [*Dobinski formula*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobi%C5%84ski%27s_formula): $$ B_n = \frac{1}{e}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{k^n}{k!}. $$ It is hard to believe that an easy closed form is available for $g(u)$.

Comment: @SangchulLee why is it hard to believe that there is an easy closed form? (I believe you, it just doesn't seem intuitive to me)

Comment: Any such formula would also tell a lot about the Bell numbers $B_n$. But no simple formula is known for $B_n$, and it seems that even asymptotic behavior of $B_n$ doesn't seem to be an easy problem to attack.